# width of div flickering between previous width and current width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed an audio slider (the slider down the bottom which allows you to scrub through the track) similar to SoundCloud's, and it all works perfectly, except for **one thing**; it *flickers* back and forth between the width [/ time] of the previous playing track, and the current playing track.

I have no idea as to why this is happening and have been stumped on it for quite a while.

This is my current block of **JavaScript** & **jQuery**:

```
function trackToSlider(wave){
    // get the duration of current playing song
    var waveDuration = wave.getDuration(); 

    // check every 0.1s how far in the song is
    var getWidthAndMax = setInterval(function(){
        // currentWidth is the current percentage of the width of the slider from 100%
        var currentWidth = (wave.getCurrentTime() / waveDuration) * 100;

        makeSliderIncrease(currentWidth, waveDuration);
    }, 100);

    function makeSliderIncrease(currentWidth, maxWidth){
        // if the current time is more than or equal to the songs duration, set the width of the slider to 100% and clear the interval 
        if(currentWidth >= maxWidth){
            clearInterval(getWidthAndMax);
            $('#inner-slider').css('width', '100%');
        // otherwise set the width percentage equal to currentwidth
        } else {
            $('#inner-slider').css('width', currentWidth + '%');
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the *relative* elements inside my **HTML**:

```
<!-- play or pause track button !-->
<div onclick="trackToSlider(wave);"></div>

<!-- the audio slider which keeps on flickering !-->
<div class="audio-slider-container">
    <div id="outer-slider">
        <div id="inner-slider"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope you all sort of understand where I am at currently. I have attempted to comment everything to make it easier to understand.

I feel like the problem is that because it's set a width already, before it moves onto the next track, when the new track attempts to set the new width, it's flicking between the two widths consistently, but I could be wrong.

All help or suggestions are appreciated,

Thanks. **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's  beacouse you use the same div for every track. My assumption is that your clearInterval function resets currentWidth of wave, and makes it go back to 0 invoking tracktoSlider twice. But that's all I can say based on given code. Try to add a #inner-slider to html each time you start a new track, and remove it each time when track ends

Comment: `wave` is the JavaScript object. How would I add it or remove it each time?

Comment: Don't add and remove wave. Just the div id="inner-slider" using document.createElement(). And if you want to remove wave, well in JS it's not as easy as in c++ e.g., but if no reference is pointing to an object it will be collected